# capture multiple images from webcam - django + js

Tags: javascript, python, django, webcam

I've a project one of the models has image field to upload picture , i made it `modelformset_factory` to upload multiple images , but from webcam ! is there any django tips or modules to do that ? i tried this but i cant take more than one picture , and cant assign taken photo into the `ImageField`?

my  image upload model

```
class Document(models.Model):
    booking =models.ForeignKey(Booking,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    docs = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_docs)
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.booking.id)
```

my forms.py

```
class UploadDocumentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['docs']

UploadDocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(Document,form=UploadDocumentsForm,extra=1,can_delete=True)
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
def add_new_image(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Booking,id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        images = UploadDocumentFormSet(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if images.is_valid():            
            for img in images:
                if img.is_valid() and img.cleaned_data !={}:
                    img_post = img.save(commit=False)
                    img_post.booking = obj
                    img_post.save()
            return redirect(reverse_lazy("booking:add_booking",kwargs={"room_no":obj.room_no.room_no}))
        else:
            messages.error(request,_('take a picture or choose an image'))    
    images = UploadDocumentFormSet(queryset=Document.objects.none())            
    return render(request,'booking/add_img.html',{'obj':obj,'images':images})
```

```js
    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
  
    const constraints = {
      video: true,
    };
  
    captureButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
      context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  
    // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then((stream) => {
        player.srcObject = stream;
      });
      
    $('#addButton').click(function() {
        var form_dex1 = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#images').append($('#formset').html().replace(/__prefix__/g,form_dex1));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_dex1) + 1);    
        
    });
```

```html
          <button id="addButton" class="px-4 py-1 pb-2 text-white focus:outline-none header rounded-xl">
            {% trans "add new form" %}
            <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
        </button>  

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" dir="ltr">{% csrf_token %}
                {% for form in images.forms %}
                {{form.id}}          

                <div id="main_form" class="text-lg">
                    <div class="border border-purple-900 mt-2 rounded-lg p-2 text-center">
                        <p>{% for i in obj.takes_by.all %}
                            {{forloop.counter}} : {{i.full_name}}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </p>
                    </div>                                
                </div>
                <hr>
                {{images.management_form}}
                <div class="form-group mt-3" id="images">
                    {{ form.docs | add_class:'form-control-file' }}
                </div>

                <video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
                <button id="capture">Capture</button>
                <canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
               
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="form-group mt-3" id="formset" style="display: none;">
                    {{ images.empty_form.docs | add_class:'form-control-file' }}

                </div>

                <button class="header pt-2  text-white px-4 p-1 rounded-lg mt-4">{% trans "save" %}</button>
            </form>
```

but im not sure how to achieve it ?!
thank you for helping

Comment: maybe first use `print()` and `console.log()` to see what you have in variables. Maybe you have to create next image with different name.

Comment: @furas but still i didnt ties captured image with backend ! im not sure how to do that

Comment: @furas i have to put canvas image into input image field

Comment: if you need many images then you may need many canvas and unique name for every field.

Comment: it is hard to say what is the problem because we can't run it. If you could create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run then we could test it.

Comment: @furas if this question will be fixed and the django version will be easy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69351438/how-to-put-captured-image-from-webcam-into-input-file i've put only html with js code

Comment: @furas now i just want to add canvas image into my input field , i very appreciate your helps , its about one week , still i cant overcome it

Comment: @furas you can test it https://jsfiddle.net/n91gfrcu/