# How to put captured image from webcam into input file

Tags: javascript, html, capture

I'm trying to upload images from webcam, but I'm not sure how to assign captured image into input file field. Here is the code:

```html
<input type="file" id="document">

<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
```

I have to put the canvas image into my input file field with `id="document"` :

```js
const player = document.getElementById('player');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
  
const constraints = {
   video: true,
};
  
captureButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   e.preventDefault();
 });
  
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
 .then((stream) => {
  player.srcObject = stream;
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

To  capture images from user's camera you can use the capture attribute set to user.

Just like this:

```
<label for="theImageFile">Upload photo from live camera:</label>
<input type="file" id="theImageFile" capture="user" accept="image/*">
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture

Comment: thank you , but it only works for mobile not computer